# OOM error causes by lots of small images (not being scaled), huge heap size

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, out-of-memory

I know that there is a lot of information on OOM issue but I have done a lot reading before asking this question I can't find an answer to it anywhere.

I'm loading a lot of small images using

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

These images are not being scaled down so insamplesize will not help.  The biggest of these images is only about 400kb.  I am getting a huge heap on my samsung galaxy s4 and I have no idea why.

> 04-27 13:38:40.023: I/dalvikvm-heap(16915): Grow heap (frag case) to
>   97.450MB for 8294416-byte allocation

Total the xhdpi images are 5.1 mb so how is my heap getting to 97.45mb???

Some of the "-byte allocation" are huge.  20 million+ which doesn't make sense to me since 400kb is only ~410,000 bytes, so why is there a 20 million byte allocation?

I have ignored this problem for a while because it works fine on all of the devices I have tested it on.  But now I am trying to use slightly higher res images (5.9mb total) and the application gets a OOM

> 04-27 13:52:28.890: E/dalvikvm-heap(22852): Out of memory on a
>   33177616-byte allocation.

And it points to

> 04-27 13:52:28.900: E/AndroidRuntime(22852):  at
>   com.example.packagename.Game.run(Game.java:534)

which is

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

this image is only 42kb!  Why does it require a 33 million byte allocation!?

Also is there anyway I can pre-load these images while the app loads?  I want to do this to speed up the transitions between views and also could these images be store in a way that would require less memory?  (They are stored in /res)

Comment: Is your "400kb" referring to a size on disk?

Comment: Yes?  It's 420kb on my computer...

Answer (score 1):

> Total the xhdpi images are 5.1 mb so how is my heap getting to 97.45mb???

PNG and JPEG image files are compressed 90-95% from their in-memory size. So, what you are seeing sounds about right.

There is quite a bit of [documentation on bitmap management](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) that you should consider reading, after you have learned more about how [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) and [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg) files work.